# Should we have a collection of aviation related humor?

Tags: discussion

Similar to the following on StackOverflow:

- [What's your favorite “programmer” cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/84556/1050256)
- [What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/234075/1050256)

I do agree that on both of the above-mentioned pages, it is specified that `... it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site ...`. But at the minimum, it does have a rich collection of programming-related humor.

What does our community thinks about such an effort about aviation?

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow: Where we hate fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Comment: The joke question on main site: [What is your favorite aviation joke?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13965/65)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that:

- The mentioned precedents exist
- We seem to have some <s>[users with a sense of humor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18682350#18682350)</s> (until it comes to questions maybe)
- We seem to have missed the [April Fool's opportunity](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/8049/3082)

I'm going to be optimistic and say **yes**, we could make one work.

Comment: Great. Should we wait for a few more people to chime in?

Comment: I think it'd be better on Meta.Aviation personally.

Answer (score 20):

Given that Both "precedents" are locked as an example of *what not to ask*.

I'm going to be a buzz kill and say **no**. It'll just invite off topic chatter and other "What is your favorite aviation related X?"

Which tend to get closed quickly on other SEs as well.

Comment: I agree. Both 'precedents' have quite a number of deleted answers, removed images, and confused people who don't get the jokes. Humour is a notoriously tricky area, especially in an international environment: one person laughs at what another finds boring, or even offensive.

Comment: I interpreted the lock as indicating that the fun ran its course. With over 100 answers, how many people are going to read a new one on the last page? And like with any other "question", if it doesn't interest someone, they don't need to go there. I'm sure ours will end up locked someday too but there's a reason the ones on SO are there and not deleted.

Comment: Also we waited almost a week and received no negative feedback here.

Comment: @fooot Another point to consider is that both those posts have almost half million and a million views.

Comment: @Farhan yes and ours is attracting views and users as well.

Comment: @Farhan not trying to shoot anyone down, but popularity (view count) doesn't ensure on-topicness. If it's off-topic (as mentioned in the [tour], i.e. Questions that are primarily opinion-based, Questions with too many possible answers [...]), then it should be closed. In addition of that, there's no answer that's acceptable, which is why it's not suitable as Q&A format. (Of course as a merely spectator on this site, I don't really have power to affect the policy, but that's my 2 cents based on reading other metas)

Comment: @fooot I agree that the process didn't work as well as it could have, but I think people responded to seeing the question and it's answers and deciding it should be closed. For me, at least a part of the decision was based on the answers it received - some good ones, but also a few offensive ones, and nothing spectacular.

Comment: @fooot the problem with meta is that there is a very low amount of people visiting it, I only found out about this meta question after the joke question was posted.

Comment: @ratchetfreak it actually was in the "hot meta post" list shown in the main site homepage

Comment: Why was this question tagged with categories? Are the categories added to limit the scope of jokes or were they added after jokes are posted? In my opinion, the joke question (should it be unlocked, which I am not in favor of) should not contain any tags.

Comment: @fooot "yes and ours is attracting views and users as well." And if we post porn or give away free beer we'll attract views and users, too. But will any of them stay and contribute usefully to the site? Attracting people by a misrepresentation of what we're about isn't a good way of attracting people: in fact, it's normally referred to by the pejorative term "bait and switch".

Comment: @DavidRicherby it's also "bait and switch" if a user (could be anyone) asks on meta "can I ask this question," only receives positive responses, asks the question, and then it gets closed. I would have expected people with such strong opinions about what is or is not acceptable on this site to visit meta more often.

Comment: @fooot Absolutely not. I did not bait: I took no action whatsoever that could be seen as supporting the question (because I was ignorant of its existence and of this discussion on Meta). I did not switch: it was impossible for me to change from pro to anti because I was never pro.

Comment: @fooot "Also we waited almost a week and received no negative feedback here." Indeed. At the time the thread was created, it was definitely reasonable to assume that the community was supportive. It's unfortunate that nobody who disagreed noticed the discussion before the question was posted.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I was not accusing you personally of bait and switch but suggesting it of the community as a whole. And I agree with that next comment.

Comment: At least [one 'joke'](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/13987/62) has sadly proven me right

Answer (score 3):

My vote is a close - although I love these jokes, its not what this site should be about.

Also, within minutes we had the [offsenive jokes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/13987/100) even when the OP specifically asked for there not to be.

Answer (score 2):

Would suggest getting ready for the next year's April 1. Posting a joke collection question **two days after** April Fools' Day isn't much fun, anyway.

By the rules, April 1st is **the** day for fun on main sites, and chat is where light-hearted banter should take place.

Answer (score -2):

Favorited to Upvoted ratio for both of those precedent questions is off the charts.  The same is happening for our question as well.

Keep the [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13965/6919) open.

Comment: So what? Favorites just mean that people expect to revisit it, not this it's on-topic. If it gets closed, it's not like it's gonna get deleted.